# How to create angular factory as per backend response?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I'm not getting how can I create angular factory having shared details in an object. What I want is these details I'm getting from server so I want this factory to get initilized before angular app starts. I want to use this details in my controller so it should be ready when user visit pages. I do implement `resolve` function so I achieved by forcing controller not to load before I'm getting details from server but this details I want to use in another factory which extract some details from it and returns few data in which I can't implement promise. Can you please suggest way how can I do this?

If you required any code and is it not clear please comment, I will provide.

Comment: If you could share a plunker which demonstrates the issue, that will surely help.

Comment: @AbhishekJain I'm not getting what to implement and which approch should I go with. what you want in plunker or jsfiddle!!

Comment: plunker or jsfiddle - either one is fine. It is just easier to understand a problem when you see it.

Comment: @AbhishekJain I know. But my problem is what I want to achieve, I don't know how to do. It's very simple I want to create factory which is an object and I want that object dynamic which is I'm getting from server so It will async so how can I stop angular for a while. This is the issue.

Comment: If I understand your situation right, you can run your custom async code first, and when it is done, you can use angular.bootstrap to bootstrap your app conditionally More information here -https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap